# JS deep merging of objects- removing empty keys

Tags: javascript, recursion, json

I've written a helper for combining objects (deep merge).

It works, and is flexible to add options (like `uniq` and `replace`).

Replace should replaces the any matching properties on the object (but spread in any existing properties).

The code below works, but I believe it could be optimized particularly as I could NOT find a way to remove empty keys without the use of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify` - it feels wrong to have to crawl back over the entire array to do so.

Using Lodash is not an option.

### Examples

DATA = {foo:{i:{z:[1]},x:[1]}}

- `getDeepMerge(DATA, {add:{foo:{q:[1]}}}`
  // {foo:{i:{},x:[1], q:[1]}}
- `getDeepMerge(DATA, {add:{foo:{}}, replace:true}`
  // {foo:{}}
- `getDeepMerge(DATA, {add:{foo:{i:{}}} }, replace:true, removeEmpty:true}`
  // {add:{foo:{i:{}}, x[1]} }

### Code

```
const removeKey = (key, {[key]: _, ...rest}) => rest;

const getNewObj = toAdd => Array.isArray(toAdd) ? getObj(toAdd) : toAdd

const DE_DUPE = (e, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) === i

const removeEmptyObj = (o) => {
  let ignores = [null, undefined, ""],
  isNonEmpty = d => !ignores.includes(d) && (typeof(d) !== "object" || Object.keys(d).length)
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o), function(k, v) {
    if (isNonEmpty(v))
      return v;
  });
}
const getDeepMerge = (ogObj, opts={})=> {
  const { add, uniq=true, replace=false, removeEmpty=false } = opts

  const isObject = obj => obj && typeof obj === 'object';
    return [ogObj, add].reduce((prev, obj) => {
      let _add = {...prev}
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        const pVal = _add[key];
        const oVal = obj[key];

        if (Array.isArray(pVal) && Array.isArray(oVal)) {
          _add[key] = pVal.concat(...oVal).filter(uniq ? DE_DUPE : null)
          if(replace){ 
_add[key] = oVal }
          _add = removeEmpty ? removeKey(key, _add) : _add

        }
        else if (isObject(pVal) && isObject(oVal)) {
            _add[key] = getDeepMerge(pVal, {...opts, add:oVal}) 
            if(replace){ 
              _add[key] = oVal
            }
        }
        else {
          _add[key] = oVal
        }
      });
      return removeEmptyObj(_add)
    }, {});
}
```

Live working demo: https://jsbin.com/yuduvukiqe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I have tried your code, but it does not output the expected result. Could you please check this?

Comment: For those in the Close vote queue: Jan's statement is correct - see the output [here](https://jsbin.com/wisozizovi/edit?js,console)